# cube root symbol does not show up in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unicode

I want to display the cube root symbol in an android app that I design. I tried the unicode for the cube root. But it does not display as the cube root symbol. It shows up as an empty box. I can not use any image because some of my answers need to show as a cube root.

Comment: What unicode code did you enter? Can you write it here?

Comment: You are probably not using the correct font or missing the font needed for the code point or symbol. We need to see some code to know for sure. If all else fails, fins a Windows box and use Microsoft's "Unicode Arial" true type font. Its got every character I have ever looked for and needed.

Comment: There is something fishy about the cube root. I changed font to arial and many others and it does not display. The typeface and the square root are instead displayed correctly. The code I used was: \u221b

Comment: I was using \u221b and it is not displaying the symbol. I also tried all the font types, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be present on older versions of Android. I worked around it by combining the unicode for superscript 3 (\u00B3) and the unicode for square root (\u221A). It quite closely resembles the actual cube root symbol.